# Solution to a Riccati type equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following Riccati type equation,

$$y'(x)-\frac{1}{4x}y(x)^{2}+\frac{y(x)}{x}-a\frac{x}{(1-x)^{2}}=0,$$

where $a$ is just a constant. I am struggling to find a substitution that makes the equation linear. I also tried to find a particular solution and use that method to solve it, but I was unable to find a solution.

Comment: $y(x)=-2xu'(x)/u(x)$ makes the equation linear.

Comment: After the edit now $y=-4xu'/u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the last term in the equation is a fraction $-\frac{a x}{(x-1)^2}$, one can guess a particular solution to be $y_1=\frac{bx+c}{x-1}$, where $b,c$ are constants which can be determined later. Then easy calculation shows
$$ (2a-2b+b^2)x^2+2b(c+2)x+c(c+2)=0$$
which holds for any $x$. So $c+2=0,2a-2b+b^2=0$ or $c=-2,b=1\pm\sqrt{1-2a}$. Then one has found a particular solution
$$y_1=\frac{(1+\sqrt{1-2a})x-2}{x-1}.$$
Now let $y=y_1+u$ to get $u$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Quick question, how does one see that a good guess is $y_1$, I can understand the $bx$ part of the numerator, but is there some hint in the equation that tells you that the $c$ is needed in $y_1$?

Comment: $c$ is needed since one can't obtain $y_1$  without $c$.